# Display less verbose function parameters - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to display function parameter information in a less verbose way than I see by default in Visual Studio. Are there any settings or methods for viewing these in a way that toggles or omits the details of the types and displays nearly just the names of the parameters?

For example, I might find something like this.
[image: Verbose function tooltip]
Would it be possible to see instead to only output the final type defs; something like this?

```
iterator insert(iterator hint, value_type &_Val)
```

That would be a real big deal for figuring out complex functions at a glance, without looking online, and it seems simple enough. Does this exist in visual studio?

Comment: If no answer to this problem exists, it seems that the best solution is to offer the idea as a feature request. I've posted one [**here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6206331-enable-intellisense-to-print-clearer-function-info). I've also created an example of the desired behavior in C++ with [**this code**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3707511eb6b8a3). Perhaps It will be possible for an acceptable answer to appear before too long.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are seeing Intellisense results. It doesn't know the abstract signatures, it's based on the actual internal implementations of the Standard Library. It's indeed not helpful at all, but it was easy to implement for Microsoft. Also, since it's based on the actual header implementation, it's never out of sync.

Comment: Maybe I didn't imply it in the sense that intellisense would simply be using the information that it had. If it knew what a namespace was, what a template was, and what a typedef was, as it was walking the signature - it really shouldn't be more than a small amount of code to toggle the output of each of them for different levels of detail... Right?

Comment: @AAorris: Intellisense knows what typedefs are, it just doesn't remember which particular typedefs were used to declare `insert`.